# Match and update values using linq from two lists?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, c#-4.0

Hi I am new to the c# and `Linq`. I am trying to update the one list if the value of some property matches the value of the other lists property.

Suppose i have one list as `firstlist`

```
   Name      code        
   ABC       101         
   DEF       201         
   GHI       301
   JKL       401
   MNO       101
```

And Second list as `secondlist`

```
  description       Code
    IT               101
    ADMIN            201
    Develeopment     301
    Testing          401
    Service          501
```

And i want my resultant list as

```
    Name      code        
    ABC       101 IT        
    DEF       201 ADMIN       
    GHI       301 Develeopment
    JKL       401 Testing
    MNO       101 IT
```

I tried something like  this ,

```
    var query = firstlist.Select(x => { x.Code = 101; return x.Code.ToString()+"IT"; })
```

But i want to match the code from the `secondlist` in place of `101` and for matching code i want to update the `firstlist` code with the `code+description` i don't have any idea how to do it if anyone suggest any way or link which will guide me would be great.

**********UPDATE****************

What i want to say is that as @Sergey suggested

```
   from x in firstlist
   join y in secondList
   on x.code equals y.Code
   select new {
       x.Name,
      code = String.Format("{0} {1}", y.Code, y.description)   
  }
```

in place of this can i just do something like this

```
   from x in firstlist
   join y in secondList
   on x.code equals y.Code
   select x.code = String.Format("{0} {1}", y.Code, y.description)
```

which will only update the existing `listone` in place of the creating new entity for each match

Comment: What if you have more than one match? Or if there is no matches for some value?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy No. I have distinct values in the `secondlist`. Suppose as the `SecondList` is the master table data and `firstlist` as the details table data

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get items which match in both lists:

```
from x in firstlist
join y in secondList
   on x.code equals y.Code
select new {
   x.Name,
   code = String.Format("{0} {1}", y.Code, y.description)   
}
```

Updating objects in first list:

```
var query = from x in firstlist
            join y in secondList
                on x.code equals y.Code
            select new { x, y };

foreach(var match in query)
   match.x.Code = String.Format("{0} {1}", match.y.Code, match.y.description);
```

Comment: what if i have the very long list of properties in the `listone` do i have to mention all of them in this `code = String.Format("{0} {1}", y.Code, y.description),someprop1,someprop2,someprop3` like this

Comment: @Curiosity if you are talking about `firstlist` and properties of `x` then you can simply select `x` entity in result: `select new { x, y }`

Comment: @Curiosity where someprop1, someprop2 comes from?

Comment: They are extra properties in the `firstlist` other than name and code so what i am saying is in place creating new entity for each match can i just update the existing value of the `code` by doing something like `x.code=y.code+y.description`

Comment: @Curiosity if you want to update items from firstlist, then you can enumerated results of query and update x.Code

Answer (score 0):

`Code` seems to be an `int`, then you cannot change it to be a `string` which contains the code + description. So this approach presumes that it's a `string`:

You can use `Enumerable.Join` to get only items which are in both according to the `Code`. Then the most efficient is to use a simple loop to update the property with the new value:

```
var firstInSecond = from first in firstlist
                    join second in secondList
                    on first.Code equals second.Code
                    select new { first, second };
foreach (var x in firstInSecond)
    x.first.Code = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.second.Code, x.second.Description);
```

Answer (score 0):

temporarily add description column to firstlist or clone it to anther table

```
firstlist.Columns.Add("description");
Datatable joinedTable = from first in firstlist
                    join second in secondList
                    on first.Code equals second.Code
                    select new DataRow[] { first , second }).Select(resultSet =>
                                          {
                                              resultSet[0]["description"] = resultSet[1]["description"];
                                              return resultSet[0];
                                          }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Update with JOIN on 2 lists with AND query, you can use JOIN and Where condition, please check below for example, 
https://codeshowtime.blogspot.com/2020/01/linq-tricks.html